# Let us create a sonnet quine!

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source, quine, source-layout

There are programs that will output its source code to standard output and do nothing else. They also access no external output. This type of program is known as a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29), and is a common code challenge.

There are poems that have the [rhyme scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme_scheme) a-b-a-b, c-d-c-d, e-f-e-f, g-g. They have 14 lines. They are usually recited in [iambic pentameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter). They are called [sonnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet).

You are to write a program/poem that is both a quine and a sonnet.

1. When saying lines, it is recommended that you only say all characters except for: whitespace and `,()[]_"'`. This is flexible depending on the language though.
2. Iambic Pentameter means 10 syllables, starting unstressed, and then alternating between stressed and unstressed. This is optional, but will mean more votes.
3. Comments are discouraged, especially to complete rhymes (although comments are very much encouraged if they can be incorporated with the code in the poem in a way that produces dramatic effect.)
4. [Cruft](http://jeremyskrdlant.blogspot.com/2012/10/what-is-cruft-code.html) is discouraged.

Voters, use the four above guidelines when voting. This is a popularity contest, so the program with the most votes wins.

Comment: This is too easy for languages like Javascript, which `(function(){return'('+arguments.callee+')()';})()` is a quine. Adding garbage after the return is enough.

Comment: I was going to attempt this one, but the restrictions imposed by creating a quine (in most languages) make it too difficult to output any kind of meaningful sonnet. Therefore the question isn't very interesting, since the sonnet will just be rhyming characters such as `/` and `-` (slash and dash).

Comment: @grovesNL You could create a different sonnet challenge.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That isn't considered a quine, since you are accessing an external resource (namely, the source code.)

Comment: @PyRulez I wasn't trying to be rude. I'm just offering some feedback, which may especially relevant if there aren't many responses for that reason.

Comment: Actually, I'm reading the arguments passed to the function. From there, I access the function itself and take the source code. It accesses itself.

Comment: @grovesNL I was serious. It would be sort of odd to completely change the question now, but if you have an idea for a sonnet challenge go ahead. I wasn't trying to be rude either.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel From wikipedia, it says quines can't use input.

Comment: @PyRulez Is there any input in it?

Comment: Code Challenge, Popularity Contest and Code Golf are mutually exclusive. You've described a popularity contest in the question text, so the code challenge tag doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I guess it's not a quine if the restriction is "the code cannot read its own source code in whatever manner"

Comment: It cannot read it's source code from **external** sources. The var `arguments` is an **internal** var to the function itself.

Comment: Wait iambic pentameter is not required? So 10 syllables per line is not required?

Comment: I don't think that this question has lived up to our sites standards in the past 3 years.  1) There is no objective definition of sonnet, making this question rather unclear.  2) There is no judging criterion other than "most creative" making this question without a proper winning criterion.  In the past it was common practice for anything to go in terms of a pop-con but that has changed.  I am going to Vote to close as unclear until this challenge is clarified.

Comment: While I undersand the intention behind giving people some leeway when it comes to pronounciation, it means that the validity of any answer is debatable, ultimately making the challenge unclear.

Comment: @Dennis that's why its a popularity contest.

Comment: Popularity contest no longer means *anything goes*. All challenges need an objective validity criterion.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby

```ruby
s = [[/t{1}he_way/,'to_a'],[/\*j{1}ewel/,'*rule']].to_a
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| s.each { |rule| code.sub! *rule } }, '-'
s = [[/t{1}he_way/,'to_a'],[/\*j{1}ewel/,'*rule']].the_way
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| s.each { |rule| code.sub! *jewel } }, '-'
-
s = [[/t{1}he_curse/,'reverse'],[/\*c{1}raze/,'*phrase']].reverse
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| s.each { |phrase| code.sub! *phrase } }, '-'
s = [[/t{1}he_curse/,'reverse'],[/\*c{1}raze/,'*phrase']].the_curse
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| s.each { |phrase| code.sub! *craze } }, '-'
-
s = [[/r{1}eject/,'collect'],[/\*b{1}ird/,'*word']].collect
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| s.each { |word| code.sub! *word } }, '-'
s = [[/r{1}eject/,'collect'],[/\*b{1}ird/,'*word']].reject
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| s.each { |word| code.sub! *bird } }, '-'
-
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| [[/\*l{1}augh/,'*half']].each { |half| code.sub! *half } }, '-'
puts <<'-'.*(2).tap { |code| [[/\*l{1}augh/,'*half']].each { |half| code.sub! *laugh } }, '-'
-
```

Don't pronounce the dashes, they're just there to delimit stanzas. Scansion's not perfect but decent.

Comment: +1 "Reverse the Curse!" would be a catchy title. I'm not crazy about the phrasing, but I got more than half a laugh out of this.